# Cannot accept GMP reward in Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here? I have Piggyback's excellent guide, but there's no mention of how GMP works. I've recently unlocked some Challenge Task rewards, and with it some GMP... great! But when I try to collect, I get a message saying "Unable to accept. You have reached your maximum item capacity."

Here's the reward: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/kax56Km.png]

Here's the error message:
[image]

Here's my finances:

[image]

I don't understand why I'm minus money locally, but have loads of money remotely... why don't they balance each other out? And why can't I accept 500,000 GMP? :(

Thanks for any help understanding this!

Comment: Just skimmed your post quickly, but if one is online and one is offline GMP, I don't believe they share. None of the other resources do, so it makes a stupid kind of sense.

Comment: @DangerZone All offline/online resources are shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a bug. Apparently completing a mission or (as I did) quitting the game and going back in sorts it all out.

Comment: Restarting the game did not work for me, doing a side mission did not work either, nor did accepting rewards from a combat deployment.  What did work was starting several new research projects, spending some GMP.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's a really weird bug that will go away in time. For me it went away when I got a different GMP reward and accepted that.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue. What I did how under Mother Base menu I did Accept Rewards cleared all that out and then I was able to accept the GMP

Comment: It's just based on time, I think.